# Old c code to ATL/COM dll

Tags: c++, c, com, atl

I have an old c dll that I want to convert to a COM server.

It only exposes one function.

This is what I have done:
I created an ATL project in VS 2010 added a simple ATL object with a wrapper function.
I added the c sources and headers
In the wrapper function I call the c function, I added the full function prototype as described in http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.5.

The following error appears:

Unresolved external symbol referenced in function

I tried everything.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the full error message/unresolved symbol?

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CreateGifFromEq referenced in function "public: virtual long __stdcall CMimeTexWrapper::CreateGifFromEqWrapper(wchar_t *,wchar_t *)" (?CreateGifFromEqWrapper@CMimeTexWrapper@@UAGJPA_W0@Z) C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MimeTexCOM\MimeTexWrapper.obj MimeTexCOM

Comment: You are forgetting to link the old DLL import library.

Comment: It is not a library, but source code. I want to make a COM dll instead of a win32 dll. But the source code is the same plus whatever is needed to make a COM dll. In my case, since I only need one function I created a simple atl object and added a wrapper function.
But thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use extern "C" when including the c-source:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "header.h"
}
```

Comment: Yes. I did that: extern "C" int CreateGifFromEq ( char *expression, char *gifFileName ); But thanks

Comment: And you didn't rename the old .c files to .cpp? Are you sure the prototype is the same as the function? The same calling convention as well (__stdcall, __cdecl)?

Comment: If I rename the file to .cpp 202 errors appear. The prototype is the same as the function. No idea about the calling convention, How do I check? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. (Renaming to .cpp would cause your linkage to change and make extern "C" wrong.) If there is no calling convention declared on the implementation side, they both use the default. Then it must be a problem with the linking process. To check the export name of the C-function, declare it as __declspec(dllexport). Compile and have a look at the dll in [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Look at the name of the function you see in this program.

Comment: You can also use dumpbin /exports your-dll

Comment: I declared the function as int __declspec(dllexport) CreateGifFromEq ( char *expression, char *gifFileName )

But in dependency walker only these functions appear:
DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetClassObject
DllInstall
DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer

And I get these two warnings:

Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

These are the two missing dlls: gpsvc.dll and ieshims.dll

I compiled in debug mode.

Comment: dumpbin /exports yields the same

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for MimeTexCOM.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    4F372D93 time date stamp Sat Feb 11 22:10:11 2012
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           5 number of functions
           5 number of names

Comment: ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000217E9 DllCanUnloadNow = @ILT+2020(_DllCanUnloadNow@0)
          2    1 00021F0F DllGetClassObject = @ILT+3850(_DllGetClassObject@12)
          3    2 00021CD5 DllInstall = @ILT+3280(_DllInstall@8)
          4    3 00021EB5 DllRegisterServer = @ILT+3760(_DllRegisterServer@0)
          5    4 00021028 DllUnregisterServer = @ILT+35(_DllUnregisterServer@0)

  Summary

       12000 .data
        2000 .idata
        B000 .rdata
        5000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
       46000 .text
       20000 .textbss

Any idea?

Comment: This shows that the function isn't getting linked with your DLL. Some suggestions: Check that obj-files are generated from the c-files containing the function. Check the liker command. You can also try removing and adding back the c-files to your project. Make sure all sources are in the same project.

Comment: Check that obj-files are generated from the c-files containing the function. [Checked] I see a mimetex.obj in the Debug folder.
Check the linker command. What do you mean by that?
This is the command line of the linker:

Comment: /OUT:"C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MimeTexCOM\Debug\MimeTexCOM.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /DLL "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEF:".\MimeTexCOM.def" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\MimeTexCOM.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MimeTexCOM\Debug\MimeTexCOM.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Comment: /PGD:"C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MimeTexCOM\Debug\MimeTexCOM.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE 

You can also try removing and adding back the c-files to your project. [DONE] I created the project from scratch at least five times.
Make sure all sources are in the same project. Visual studio wizard creates two projects: MimeTexCOM and MimeTexCOMPS. I dont know what is MimeTexCOMPS for.

Comment: I meant checking the build log but I'm not 100% sure it contains the relevant information. Otherwise I'm clueless. You could try creating a non ATL/COM-project (normal Win32 exe) and see if that works.

Comment: This is the log: http://pastebin.com/6HLz5Rpi  What is happening is really odd, isn it?

Comment: Yes, it's odd. From the log it is apparent that c-files are compiled to obj and linked. But, you have a def-file, which might explain why the c-function didn't appear in the exports. However, that build log succeeded.The bottom line is that there must be some kind of mismatch between your c++ declaration and the c-function implementation. I don't think I can do much more at this end.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. I dont see the mismatch, but I am not a c/c++ guy so I cannot tell. I am more a c# guy.

Comment: This is the def file

; MimeTexCOM.def : Declares the module parameters.

LIBRARY

EXPORTS
 DllCanUnloadNow  PRIVATE
 DllGetClassObject PRIVATE
 DllRegisterServer PRIVATE
 DllUnregisterServer PRIVATE
 DllInstall  PRIVATE

Comment: If I add the function in this file I get the following error:

Error 180 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CreateGifFromEq C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MimeTexCOM\MimeTexCOM.def 1 1 MimeTexCOM

Comment: Is the C-function declared static?

Comment: Not it was not declared as static. I did it now.
But now in the wrapper this error appears: Error 1 error C2159: more than one storage class specified c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mimetexcom\mimetexwrapper.cpp 8 1 MimeTexCOM

Answer (score 1):

You might try compile the c dll to a regular win32 dll, then calling it from you COM dll through a wrapper. You would need 2 dlls, but if the original DLL will compile fine, you should be able to use it from COM.

Comment: Thanks but that is not an option. I am trying to build a COM dll because It would simplify the deployment of a C# application that uses this c code.
This c# application is now using a win32 dll and we want to switch to COM if it is possible.